# Saving an offline single html page application - dynamically filled with crud javascript - on client side only

Tags: javascript, save, single-page-application, offline

I'm very new here and hope I can express myself clearly.

I'm a teacher and I'd like to create a single html file with interactivity (kind of empty form) that can be loaded without any server : student should for example be provided a file like myform.html.

This means html, css and javascript should all be in the document.

Once the students have opened and filled their names and answers, i'd like them to be able to save locally the modified document as another .html - Let's say johndoeform.html - file.

If I load a simple html file from my local storage and I fill - for example textareas - and try to save the modified page with "save as" in my web browser (safari) I get the unmodified page when I open it again.

I'm aware that an app that stores a lot of datas should rely on a server and data base app. But for a simplistic form/quiz that really should be loaded without any additional software nor an internet connection I feel that this way should be more straight forward.

I'm a noob with java script and I've seen quite some things around about generating blobs with html content but I'm not sure how to get the whole modified document, generate a blob with it then save the whole thing via a new html document.

Perhaps a JS generated download link could do the trick ?

For the purpose here's a simple example of code I could use :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Search on wikipedia</h3>

    What's the difinition of ENERGY:<br>
    <textarea id="energyDef" placeholder="Write your definition here and save your work" cols=40 rows=6>
    </textarea>

    <p>Click the button to save as an html file.</p>

    <button type="button" onclick="saveHtml()">Save</button>

<script>
function saveHtml() {
  // how can I generate and export the whole modified page from here
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by giving the answer and saying you probably shouldn't do this and instead below for reason and better solutions

You can take the value of the textarea and directly modify the innerText of it to hard code the answer into the html and then simply export it by using a blob

You can add classes to the answer field and loop through it so that you wouldn't have to manually enter the code for each field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Search on wikipedia</h3>

    What's the difinition of ENERGY:<br>
    <textarea id="energyDef" placeholder="Write your definition here and save your work" cols=40 rows=6></textarea>

    <p>Click the button to save as an html file.</p>

    <button type="button" onclick="saveHtml()">Save</button>

<script>
function saveHtml() {
    answer_field = document.getElementById("energyDef");
    answer_field.innerText = answer_field.value;

    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([document.documentElement.outerHTML], {type: "text/plain"});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = "dump.html";
    a.click()
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

A better way would be to export the data as a machine readable file like JSON , and implement a simple drag and drop to load the data back if you need it as shown in the html file.

Having it as a machine readable format would allow a much easier time to import into a database in the future or simply allow you to easily be able to write a script to get percentage of correct answer for a given question by the class for simple fixed answer

It would also allow you to quickly glance just the answers with a simple notepad program if proper formatting was used in the export process, ie the "space" parameters in `JSON.stringify()`